# How to count depth images from kinect

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using a Kinect with depth_viewer.  I'm able to view depth images, but  I'd like to be able to view and store a fixed number of them (say, 100).  If I put a counter in my main program, it does not increment.  If I put the same counter in the subscriber callback function to openni_camera, it does not increment (I'm guessing it gets reset on every received message).

I would think this is easy... but I'm not sure how to approach it.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Paul

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11808/how-to-count-depth-images-from-kinect/) by [Paul0nc](https://answers.ros.org/users/1067/paul0nc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 271 on 2011-11-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should use a global variable to store the number.

---

Originally posted by [lucascoelho](https://answers.ros.org/users/1016/lucascoelho/) with karma: 497 on 2011-11-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucascoelho](https://answers.ros.org/users/1016/lucascoelho/) on 2011-11-05**:
You can use more than 1 arguments. To know how to do it, please see that page: http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers . A static variable is not deleted if your program go out of the function. So it will have the previous value if the function is called again.

**Comment by [Paul0nc](https://answers.ros.org/users/1067/paul0nc/) on 2011-11-05**:
Declaring the local variable in the callback function to be a 'static int' solved the problem.

**Comment by [Paul0nc](https://answers.ros.org/users/1067/paul0nc/) on 2011-11-05**:
The callback argument is the depth image from the kinect.  Can I add any other arguments?

**Comment by [lucascoelho](https://answers.ros.org/users/1016/lucascoelho/) on 2011-11-05**:
That's strange because we don't need to define a global variable again inside the callback function. What arguments are your callback function using?

**Comment by [Paul0nc](https://answers.ros.org/users/1067/paul0nc/) on 2011-11-05**:
I tried this.  It yielded a compilation error that the variable was not defined within the scope of the callback function.